# SomeOne please explain the function of "* while a and b *" in the merge subroutine in the following mergesort program.

Tags: list, python-2.7, mergesort

SomeOne please explain the function of "* while a and b *" in the merge subroutine in the above mergesort program.

```
def merge(a):
    l = len(a)
    if (l > 1):
        n = l//2
        lsSorted = merge_sort(a[:n])
        rsSorted = merge_sort(a[n:])
        B = merge (lsSorted ,rsSorted)
        return B
    else:
        return a


def merge(a,b):
    sorted_list = []
    while a and b:
        if a[0] <= b[0]:
            sorted_list.append(a.pop(0))
        else:
            sorted_list.append(b.pop(0))
    sorted_list += a + b
    return(sorted_list)
```

Also, Where can we use logial AND with Lists?

Answer (score 0):

It's checking to see that both a and b are non-empty lists. Empty lists are a false-y value in Python.